# apply force to a body in touchesMoved direction in box2d iphone

Tags: iphone, box2d

I am new to box2d.  I have a problem i.e

when i touch the body and touchmoved(In touchmoved method i don't want move the body)upto some place and touch released.

in touchend i apply force like this...

```
     b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(0.0,15.0);

     ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(force);
```

and find out the angle b/w touchbegin point to touchend point in this way

```
    float angleRadians = atan2(touchBegin.x - touchEnd.x, touchBegin.y - touchEnd.y);
    float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
    cocosAngle1 = -1 * angleDegrees;
```

in that time,how to apply force to the body with cocosAngle1(touchend direction). Like paper in "Paper Toss" game.

how to apply force in touchmoved direction of body?...

please explain to me...

Comment: You can use ApplyForce or ApplyLinearImpulse to make a body move in a given direction. Flesh out your question with more info about what you are doing so far and what the problem is for more help.

Comment: Have you got solution?